# C++ reference to the addition of variables?

Tags: c++, pointers

how is this code snippet translated by the c++ compiler?

```
int i = 5;
int j = 4;
int *p = &j + i;
```

It creates a pointer 'p' equal to,

1. the address of j + the address of i?
2. the address of j + i?

or something else?

Comment: It exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an array out of bounds.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "**[expr.add]/4** If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 <= i + j <= n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." Just forming an invalid pointer already exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That paragraph leaves little room for interpretation: the expression `P + J` exhibits undefined behavior when `i + j > n`. I don't see how it can be read any other way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What's undefined is the *behavior* of the program containing this expression. A value (of the pointer, or the pointee) cannot be undefined; at best, it could be unspecified.  But the standard doesn't talk about unspecified values here; it talks about undefined behavior. If the index is within bounds, the result is a pointer pointing to a certain element; otherwise, if the index is out of bounds, the behavior is undefined. The language of the standard is uncharacteristically plain and unequivocal here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Also, you claim that it should be possible to form a pointer out of bounds, and then bring it back into bounds. But the standard says nothing about the result of the expression when `P` does not initially point to some element of the array. If you believe that `P+J` (with `J` out of bounds) is valid but we just can't say what it points to, then what allows you to say that `(P + J) - J` reliably produces `P`? I don't see how one can read both these things at the same time into this paragraph.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Whatever. Forget I said anything. I've deleted my comments, you should do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `&` operator has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `+`, you add to the address of the `j` the value of `i`, thus, you have **undefined behavior** if you'll try to dereference this pointer (`p` points to an invalid memory address). As was noted in the comments, an invalid address assign by itself does no harm, but the situation will become disastrous when such pointer is dereferenced.

As a demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int i = 3;
    int j = 333;
    int *p = &j + i;
    std::cout << "Address before: " << &j << '\n';
    std::cout << "Address after: " << p << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(int): " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
Address before: 0x7fff809f9998
Address after: 0x7fff809f99a4 // Address before + three sizeof(int)
sizeof(int): 4
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau Per **[expr.add]/4**, `&j + i` expression in itself already exhibits undefined behavior (unless `i == 0` or `i == 1`; here, it is not).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is it? Please, provide a reference for this. We even can have a `nullptr` sitting around quietly, until we assign and then use it. Same for any address, until we touch it. Ain't there's not much of the "behavior" while it just contains an address? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "**[expr.add]/4** If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 <= i + j <= n`; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**" Emphasis mine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for your input! Will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 5;
int j = 4;
int *p = &j + i;
```

Here **p** is pointer variable of type **int**. So it will store address of **int** variable. So on line no. 3, `int *p = &j +i;` ,you are storing address of **j** + variable **i**.
So let address of j is 100 and **i** is given as 5 , so it will store `100+5`=105 address in **p**. And this address 105 does not contain any value for now. So output depend on compiler . it may give garbage value or error or 0 as a output.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int j = 4;
    *(&j + i)=10;
    int *p = &j + i;
    
    cout<<*p;

    return 0;
}
```

So you can try above program, on line 3 we are storing 10 at address 105.

Comment: In pointer arithmetic, the pointer is adjusted by an *even multiple* of the type that is being pointed at. In this case, since `j` is an `int`, the address resulting from `&j + i` would be `addressof(j) + (sizeof(int) * i)`, ie `(100 + (4*5)) = 120`, not `105` since `sizeof(int)` is not 1.

Comment: ya that's write, pointer directly incremented by its inbuild data type. so adding 1 to int type pointer, increment address by 4 byte..

Comment: ya , that's write. adding 1 to int type pointer increment its address by 4 bits.
i just write that for explaination

Answer (score 0):

here,

the pointer 'p' is assigned or computed this way:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         **"**(**address of j**) + **j * sizeof**  **(** int or pointer's-datatype **)** **"**.
But this not a valid statement in **c++** (or **any language**) because we cannot assign or cannot give an any **random address** to the **pointer**, as address assignation(means **memory-allocation**) is only and automatically done by the compiler only.

**to see above computation**:- you can see it by typecasting hexadecimal-value to int-value like this:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 7;
    int j = 5;
    cout << i << endl;
    cout << &i << endl;
    cout << int(&i) << endl;
    cout << j << endl;
    cout << &j << endl;
    cout << int(&j) << endl;

    int *p = &j + i;

    cout << p << endl;
    cout << int(p) << endl; // here int(p) = int(&j)+i*(sizeof(int))

    return 0;
}
```